# When can we use the verb "perform" with the noun "work"?

Tags: collocations

When can we use the verb "perform" with the noun "work"? Does it suggest any special idea? or is it simply a formal way to say "do work"?

Comment: Have a look at [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=they+performed+work%2Cthey+carried+out+work&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthey%20performed%20work%3B%2Cc0) based on the ***AmE*** corpus, then switch it to ***BrE***. As you'll see, Brits favour ***they carried out work***, where Americans favour ***they performed work***. In relaxed conversational contexts I'd probably just say ***I did [some] work [for someone]***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Not that this has any direct bearing on the verb, but I think everybody would use *a high-performing [something]* or *a high-performance [something]* over the alternatives.

Comment: @JasonBassford: I can certainly get my head around ***Low-performing** students are associated with disciplinary breakdown in some schools*, so I suppose I'd have to accept ***high-performing students*** in some structurally similar sentence. I'm sure I'd stick with ***high-performance*** for the vast majority of contexts, but I'm not exactly sure how to articulate any kind of definition for those situations where I *would* specifically choose ***high-performing***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It certainly wouldn't be considered idiomatic to say *he is a high-performance agoraphobic*. Instead, we would say *he is a high-performing agoraphobic.* (I suppose the alternative to that would be *he is a highly functioning agoraphobic.*) Perhaps it's the sense of personhood that would determine *high-performing*; meanwhile, objects would be considered *high-performance*.

Comment: Hmm. Is that it? Does the ***-ing / -ance*** choice depend on whether ***function*** is a potentially synonymous replacement for ***perform**?* That seems to work for physically / mentally impaired people, but *they* don't have any choice (something about them doesn't "work" properly). But with my "students", the implication is they do (or don't) *want* to "perform" (play their part, do what the teacher wants them to do). Still not quite nailed, I feel.